# how to make recursive post requests?

Tags: ajax, recursion, promise, async-await, fetch

Hello i have to send multiple images on the server but i have to send them one at the time, i use this function to convert the image in a base64 string and then send it

```
function RiduciImgFile2(input) {
    let ido = 0
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var file = input;
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            img.onload = function (w) {
                var MAX_WIDTH = 1024;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;

                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var Dati = [];
                Dati.push(dataurl, ido)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'Run?pr=save_photo',
                    data: JSON.stringify(Dati),
                    success: function (r) {
                        // OK
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        // ERROR
                    },
                    traditional: true
                });


            };
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

is there a way with promises to do something like this

```
function files(){
   let f = document.querySelector("#input").files;
   for(let i = 0; i< f.files.length; i++){
          RiduciImgFile2(f[i])
   }

}
```

and waiting for the function RiduciImgFile2() to complete the request?Or maybe there is a recursive way?

Comment: why do you HAVE to send them one at a time?

Comment: cuz if i send too many (or too big) images the server gives me a timeout error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one way of doing it will be using forEach and axios (you'll have to import this library). Otherwise, use fetch that is similar and it's part of JS.

```
files.forEach(file => {
   postImg(file);
})

function postImg(file) {
   axios.post(url, file).then(() => {
      //something to happen if POST is successful 
   }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

This is one way of solving it, however, find out more about how to make multiple queries. I'm not sure loops are the best way of doing this.